# Where is the .git repository stored on Microsoft TFS 2015

Tags: git, tfs

I have a new TFS 2015 server which we're using with Git, and I need to ensure that it is backed up properly.

In a standard TFS server, I'd just back up the SQL server database to ensure that the TFS is backed up.

In a standard .Git "server", I'd back up the .git directory on the machine that has been designated to be the server in which the repositories are placed for the purposes of backup.

However, I'm having some difficulty in determining where the .git directory would be on a TFS server when one uses it as a front-end for .git.

I need to ensure our repositories are safely backed up to tape - does anyone know how TFS implements git repos, and in particular where the actual .git directory would be stored for each repository that is being served up by TFS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In TFS the Git repository is stored in the SQL database together with all the other data. [As long as you have a correctly configured full server backup of the TFS server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552295.aspx), your Git Repositories are safe.

[image]

There is no local folder on the TFS server containing the repositories.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft contribute a git backend to store git objects in a database. So they are all here. If backuping the database is not enough, you could have a look at generating a git bundle and backup this file. I think it is even a good practice to have a second way ( easier to do, handle and verify) , to do a backup.

Comment: Thanks heaps for that :-)

Comment: Even though they're safe in the database, I've got one concern that's making me nervous: If somebody accidentally deletes a branch in a typical git rep, I can `git fsck` on the console to find the deleting commit and then `git checkout branchname hash` to restore. If the git repo is in the database, how could I restore a deleted branch?

Comment: @ReacherGilt you have a few  options: Restore the TFS project collection to a previous point in time (to a second machine), clone the repo, commit the changes back to the original repo. Or, since TFS does no garbage collection (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/congyiw/2015/12/14/why-does-cloning-from-vsts-return-old-unreferenced-objects/) clone the repo fetching everything locally `git pull --all`, then the deleted commits should be in there and can be restored up to the time until which the TFS server adds it's internal cleanup processes.